# Where can I get XSD schema for solrconfig.xml and schema.xml

Tags: lucene, solr

I want the XML schemas defining what elements can appear where in solrconfig and schema XML files, for some IDE completion help, and also to handwrite some config, instead of copy pasting from the net where there is some mixed content for many solr versions. I'm using Solr 3.3 (which has Lucene 3.3 under it).

I cannot find it in the svn, or anywhere else for that matter. Maybe Lucene has the XSD for the schema.xml which looks a lot like mapping to a document in lucene.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [patch attached to this issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-1758).

Comment: Thanks, while this is close to what I'm looking for, I fear it is inferred from the XML file using inference tool (I also did this with XSDInferance). I'm marking your answer right, I still want the Dev-written one, if it is available at all.

Comment: It has some 96 global elements, and does not tell which goes inside what. At all.

Comment: @Zasz: there isn't a "dev-written one" because it's rather loose to be totally useful. If the patch isn't good enough, improve it and attach it to the JIRA issue.